# Flutter Row with CrossAxisAlignment.stretch throws error BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

Not sure why this throws the error `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height`

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
           Text('OK'),
           Text('Then')
       ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Without the `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` there's no problem but I need the element in the row to stretch from the top of the screen all the way to the bottom.

I get the same error when trying to use `Expanded` around either the individual text widgets or around a Column containing the text widgets.

Answer (score 4):

You wrap your `Row` in `IntrinsicHeight` first.

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[Text('OK'), Text('Then')],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't throw an error

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[Text('OK'), Text('Then')],
      ))
    ],
  ),
);
```

**UPD:**
If you want to stretch your `Text`s - I think, you don't need `Column`

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('OK'),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('Then'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, this should be accepted as the answer

Comment: I don't really get why adding `Expanded` to the `Row` makes the elements *inside* the row expanded. I thought you need to add `Expanded` to the elements inside to make them expand to the full width or height.

Answer (score 0):

Move CrossAxisAlignment.stretch to the column.

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[Text('OK'), Text('Then')],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

to have the elements stretch top to bottom reorganise everything

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Align(child: Text('OK')),
          ),
          Container(
              color: Colors.amberAccent, 
              child: Align(child: Text('Then')))
        ],
      ))
    ],
  ),
```

Just saw Andrey's answer and realised you don't even need the CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

```
  Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Align(child: Text('OK')),
          ),
          Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Align(child: Text('Then')))
        ],
      ))
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Just wondering why the row isn't stretched to fill the width of the main column even though it's contained within an Expanded widget?

Comment: Shouldn't `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` on the Row be making the Containers inside stretch to fill the width of the screen? I'm using columns instead of the containers and they don't stretch...

Comment: I'm not able to test right now, but I added colors to the container to make it easier to see what was going on. I would suggest playing around to figure out why it behaves this way.

Comment: Yeah Flutter is pretty weird. In fact I ended up getting it all to work but with no alignment at all on either the column or the row. In any cas, the key thing that was preventing it all working for me was the Expanded that needed to be around the Row. I'm still not even sure *why* that is needed since I thought Expanded was to expand things *inside* of a widget, rather than putting it on the outside to stretch out the inner elements.

Comment: A Column takes entire height of parent but a Row doesn't it takes the entire width.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be that way. I just posted another question since it seems I need to contain the whole thing in a Column since I need another element at the bottom, but now of course it doesn't work again. But my problem this time is that the Columns don't take the entire width of the parent..

Comment: Actually if you have a moment maybe you could have a look at it since the only answer so far is using Mediaquery calls but I'm sure that is not the way to do it. If it really is then this must be yet another Flutter bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203505/flutter-stretch-columns-to-full-screen-height

Comment: Here's a bit on how the layout engine works: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2