# Flutter stretch columns to full screen height

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

All three elements are at the top of the screen and stretch to fill the width, but I want them to stretch to fill the screen vertically from top to bottom.

I tried adding a `Row` around everything but it throws the error `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded`? So I tried wrapping that `Row` in an `Expanded` widget which throws the error 'Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets'.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
  body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 20),
    Row(
      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,//throws error
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Is this more like what you are after?

Each container contains a column allowing you to add multiple widgets.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Screenshot of code running]

Answer (score 12):

Here's the way to distribute your containers evenly (both horizontaly and verticaly):

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Looks good but the text in the containers need to be in columns like in my original code. So each box can contain multiple elements.

Comment: This is right, just needs a minor tweak. Instead of the Text widget being the child of the Container, the child is a Column. You just need to add the following parameters to the Column `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

Comment: Also, you can use ListView instead of Column to avoid content overflow warnings

Answer (score 7):

To get columns to take up the full width of the display and to share the height equally I did the following:

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

*Expanded* widget will share the height while the *SizedBox* widget will take up the whole width with width is set to double.infinity.

Answer (score 3):

*This may not directly answer your question*

`Column`, by default stretches to full height (it can be changed using `size: MainAxisSize.min`), so maybe you're talking stretching the height of its children. For that you should use `Expanded`.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ChildWidget1(),
    Expanded( // <-- Use Expanded with SizedBox.expand
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: ChildWidget2(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### final Edit version 4:

this should work with the columns

```dart
     return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF222222),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('Left', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('Right', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
           Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text('Bottom', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: You're using calls to get the height? Surely that's not the way to do it, it should be able to just stretch to fill the screen like it does with the width in the columns using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`. It shouldn't need any `height` parameters at all I'm sure.

Comment: Ok that looks better now, I thought you were using MediaQuery everywhere. But you've turned the `Columns` into `containers`? They need to be `Columns`.

Comment: funny thing.. if you wrap your outer Column in a Container u dont need to call the height at all..

Comment: You mean wrapped in Containers wrapped in Expanded?

Comment: Yeah I'm still struggling with it as well. Flutter is a nightmare for this kind of thing. If only it worked like CSS lol.

Comment: It's working a bit, but the bottom container has no height. Is that how it is for you? It should look like in the image attached in the other answer. If you change the colours of each box it's easier to see what I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196994/discussion-between-markus-hein-and-hasen).

Comment: Are you sure all the brackets are correct? For some reason I can't seem to copy this in.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapping the `Column` with a `ConstrainedBox` is the best solution I could come up with.